# WSO2 APIM v2.0 - User sign up deprecated

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I notice the user sign up api in the list of store api's has been deprecated and no alternate is provided.

How do we facilitate, end user sign up to handle oauth2.0 access token generation when the user itself not created in the embedded identity store of APIM v2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're correct. But you have to use it since that's the only option available.

Note that this API is available in APIM 2.1.0 too.

Comment: Cool thanks for the confirmation. Is an API made available for user password reset?